# Android app force close

Tags: java, android

I am new to android world and just started with some examples to gain understanding. In this example I am trying to display image from url but when i start the emulator and click on app icon it force closes.

```
the java file is:-



  import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Lab1Activity extends Activity{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/android.png");
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        }

        private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
        {
        try
        {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

        return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
        }
        }
        }
```

android manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="cmpe235.lab1"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Lab1Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

at console DDMS i get this error:-

```
[2011-10-23 12:13:51 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

So how to handle this nullpointer access? Thanks

Comment: That stacktrace doesn't have anything to do with your code, it doesn't even contain your class `Lab1Activity`. Is there some error in logcat that actually involves `Lab1Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not download the image when the app starts, proberly that causes the exception:

```
Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/android.png"); 
    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Save the image to your 3 res/drawable folders and load it like this, if you want it as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>     
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/youresavedfile"
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the possible locations for NullPointerException I can see are in the line where you set the drawable into the image. They might be either because your image view is null, or because the drawable is null. I suggest you to check if the image view is null before operating it, and check if an exception was thrown in your downloading method.